# Whats the different between override the update method inside view and inside serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new in django i know this is a naive question but im so confused about when exactly do we have to override update method located in view and when do we have to override update method located in serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

1) Creating, Updating in [views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods):

- `perform_create(self, serializer)`
- `perform_update(self, serializer)`
- `perform_destroy(self, serializer)`

  - > These hooks are particularly useful for setting attributes that are implicit in the request, but are not part of the request data. For instance, you might set an attribute on the object based on the request user, or based on a URL keyword argument.
  - > These override points are also particularly useful for adding behavior that occurs before or after saving an object, such as emailing a confirmation, or logging the update.
  - > You can also use these hooks to provide additional validation, by raising a ValidationError(). This can be useful if you need some validation logic to apply at the point of database save.

2) Creating, Updating in [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances):

- > If we want to be able to return complete object instances based on the validated data we need to implement one or both of the .create() and .update() methods.
- > **If your object instances correspond** to Django models you'll also want to ensure that these methods save the object to the database.
- **Also you can override create, update methods for [nested operations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-update-methods-for-nested-representations).**